# First project alarm clock

Tags: python, tkinter, button, setalarmclock

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from time import strftime 
import winsound

clock = Tk()

clock.title("WhatAClock")

clock.geometry("300x400")

notebook = ttk.Notebook()

tab1_timedate = Frame(notebook)

tab2_alarm = Frame(notebook)

tab3_timer = Frame(notebook)
 
notebook.add(tab1_timedate, text="Time and Date")

notebook.add(tab2_alarm, text="Alarm")

notebook.add(tab3_timer, text="Timer")

notebook.pack(expand=TRUE, fill="both")


def realtime():

    time_str = strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    l1_time_timedate.config(text= time_str)

    l1_time_alarm.config(text= time_str)

    clock.after(1000, realtime)


def alarm(alarm_set):

    while True:

        time_str_alarm = strftime("%H:%M:%S")

        if time_str_alarm == alarm_set :

            winsound.playsound("sound.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)

        break


def set_alarm():

    alarm_set  = f"{user_h.get()}:{user_m.get()}:{user_s.get()}"

    alarm(alarm_set)

    
l1_time_timedate =  Label(tab1_timedate)

l1_time_alarm = Label(tab2_alarm)

l1_time_timedate.place(x=20, y=30)

l1_time_alarm.place(x=20, y=30)


user_h = StringVar()

user_m = StringVar()

user_s = StringVar()


entry_h = Entry(tab2_alarm, textvariable= user_h)

entry_m = Entry(tab2_alarm, textvariable= user_m)

entry_s = Entry(tab2_alarm, textvariable= user_s)

entry_h.place(x=100, y=30)

entry_m.place(x=130, y=30)

entry_s.place(x=160, y=30)


button_alarm = Button(tab2_alarm, command= set_alarm, text= "SET ALARM")

button_alarm.place(x=100, y=70)


realtime()

                                                 
clock.mainloop()
```

"Total noob again, can t figure out why the button doesn t do what it s supposed to, any clue?

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues:

- the hour, minute and second of `alarm_set` are not zero padded. So if hour is 1 and minute is 2 and second is 3, then `alarm_set` will be `"1:2:3"`. However `time_str_alarm` is something like `"01:02:03"`, therefore the checking will not be what you want.
- don't use while loop inside `alarm()` as it will block tkinter `mainloop()` from processing pending events.  Use `after()` like in `realtime()`
- `winsound.playsound(...)` should be `winsound.PlaySound(...)` instead

Below is the modified code:

```py
def alarm(alarm_set):
    time_str_alarm = strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    if time_str_alarm == alarm_set:
        # time reached, play sound
        winsound.PlaySound("sound.wav",winsound.SND_ASYNC)
    else:
        # time not reached, keep checking
        clock.after(1000, alarm, alarm_set)


def set_alarm():
    # zero padded hour, minute and second
    alarm_set = f"{user_h.get():02}:{user_m.get():02}:{user_s.get():02}"
    alarm(alarm_set)
```

Comment: <3 Would have taken me hours!